# how restrict access for object in communities

Tags: profile, sharing, permission-sets, partner-communities, order

I have created a community where i need to restrict the access for Order object.

I have created permission set and given "Order" object access : read and edit
Also, selected permission set in community admin settings.

Still i can perform CRUD operations for order object for community user.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Remember to change permissions on the profile being used for the community users too.

Comment: on profile we can chnage permission as its disabled for "partner Community user" profiles

Comment: Also check the Organisation Wide Defaults for the objects on Security Settings

Comment: OWD for Order set as private

Answer (score 1):

we can do it by cloning the profile and then can give access to objects

Comment: @sumit. The issue with your answer is that while it's on the right track, you omitted some important details. It doesn't give enough of the needed details to be real use to the person who asked the question. Compare your answer with FernandoGavinho answer and you'll understand. More complete answers are ones that get upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

Permissions are not restrictive. Wich means that most "free" permissions will also take place. In order to restrict access, first you must REMOVE access for that profile and then you can grant access for some users by applying the permission set.